# How to show kdeplot in a 5*4 subplot?

Tags: machine-learning, seaborn, subplot

I am working on a machine learning project and am using the seaborn kdeplot to show the standard scaler after scaling. However, no matter how large the figure size I change, the graphs just can't show and will show the error: **AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'**.The image I'm willing to show is a 5*4 subplot that look like this:
[expected subplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRvVJ.png)

```
#feature scaling
#since numerical attributes have very different scales, 
#we use standardization to get all attributes to have the same scale
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(train_set)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_df, columns=["SaleAmount","SaleCount","ReturnAmount","ReturnCount",
                     "KeyedAmount","KeyedCount","VoidRejectAmount","VoidRejectCount","RetrievalAmount",
                         "RetrievalCount","ChargebackAmount","ChargebackCount","DepositAmount","DepositCount",
                  "NetDeposit","AuthorizationAmount","AuthorizationCount","DeclinedAuthorizationAmount","DeclinedAuthorizationCount"])
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10), ncols=5, nrows=4)
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['SaleAmount'], ax=axes[0])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['SaleCount'], ax=axes[1])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['ReturnAmount'], ax=axes[2])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['ReturnCount'], ax=axes[3])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['KeyedAmount'], ax=axes[4])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['KeyedCount'], ax=axes[5])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['VoidRejectAmount'], ax=axes[6])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['VoidRejectCount'], ax=axes[7])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['RetrievalAmount'], ax=axes[8])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['RetrievalCount'], ax=axes[9])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['ChargebackAmount'], ax=axes[10])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['ChargebackCount'], ax=axes[11])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['DepositAmount'], ax=axes[12])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['DepositCount'], ax=axes[13])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['NetDeposit'], ax=axes[14])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['AuthorizationAmount'], ax=axes[15])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['AuthorizationCount'], ax=axes[16])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['DeclinedAuthorizationAmount'], ax=axes[17])
sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['DeclinedAuthorizationCount'], ax=axes[18])
```

Comment: `axes` is a 2D numpy array with shape (4,5), not a 1D array with shape 20!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know that you have a two dimension array so something like this:

```
  sns.kdeplot(scaled_df['DeclinedAuthorizationCount'], ax=axes[9,2])
```